# Windows JDK8: When will the windows system reuse the handle value of a process object?

Tags: windows, winapi, java-8, process, win32-process

### Environment

jdk8 on windows

### Steps

1. Create a `Process` instance with `ProcessBuilder`, and do some tasks using the process's output.
2. Call `waitFor()` to wait for this process to complete.
3. Use jna+cmd to forcibly kill the process. I do this in a `finally` block to make sure that the process is always terminated.

```java
Field f = process.getClass().getDeclaredField("handle");
f.setAccessible(true);
long handleValue = f.getLong(process);
WinNT.HANDLE handle = new WinNT.HANDLE();
handle.setPointer(Pointer.createConstant(handleValue));
Kernel32 kernel = Kernel32.INSTANCE;
int pid = kernel.GetProcessId(handle);
Process killPr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c taskkill /pid " + pid + " /f /t");
killPr.waitFor();
killPr.destroy();
```

### Question

Is it safe to do above steps? Will I kill another unrelated process in step 3? I debugged and notice that the `handle` value of `ProcessImpl` is still valid after the process is exited. I'm worried that windows system will reuse the same handle when **the real process** is exited but **the process object** is not recycled by the jvm.

Comment: When you are using native calls via JNA anyway, why don’t you call `TerminateProcess` directly instead of launching an external process running a command line interpreter executing the `taskkill` command to eventually doing the desired call?

Comment: @Holger I'm not sure if `TerminateProcess` would kill all child processes as well. The api document says that this method will **Terminates the specified process and all of its threads**. The `/t` parameter of `taskkill` will do that, see [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill)

Comment: Well, I’m not that deep into the Windows API, but it’s obvious that there must be a function that `taskkill` will invoke, as the `taskkill`  command is nothing but software. So calling, whatever function `taskkill` uses, directly via JNA would be the simpler option. In the end, you want to destroy a `Process`  and if you think, calling `destroy()` on it is not sufficient, it’s a twisted solution to launch a new `Process` and eventually rely on calling `destroy()` on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Process handle becomes available for reuse only after the last handle to the process is closed](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110107-00/?p=11803/). As long as you can ensure that `process` doesn't get cleaned up, killing the process by PID is fine. Also, there are more cleaner ways to kill the process since you are already using JNA, see `kernel32.TerminateProcess`.

The handle for the `process` will be closed in finalize, also `Process` class has a call to `destroy()` that will also trigger a `TerminateProcess` call. Mostly you don't have to do what you are doing here. Calling `destroy` followed by `waitFor` should do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. If I understand it correctly, as long as the ProcessImpl java object isn't recycled by the jvm, the handle to the actual system process won't be closed?